# putting buttons on masterdetail template xcode

Tags: xcode

My question is, what is the most appropriate way to put my own buttons on the upper bar of the Master view in a MasterDetail template.

I would like to put my own buttons on the Top portion of the Master view in the MasterDetail template.  It arrives with an edit button on the left and an add (+) button on the right.   I commented out the Edit button in the .m file.  I drug in my own button in its place.  The first thing I noticed is that my button looks different then the + button on the right.  It seems to be of uniform size.  The next thing is that when I created my button, it did not have a place to specify the Event (touch up inside).  Could I have somehow modified the self.editButtonItem.  Surely this is a common thing to do - to replace their buttons w/ ours.  thaks

Comment: Control-drag from the button in the xib/storyboard into your .m file. This way you can create an action for the button.

Answer (score 2):

Create two custom buttons and set on the navigation item..

```
// Set navigation left button
UIButton *btnLeft = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[btnLeft setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button_signup.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btnLeft addTarget:self action:@selector(skipImage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[btnLeft setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 29)];
[btnLeft setTitle:@"Skip" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btnLeft setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btnLeft .titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Futura" size:15.0]];
UIBarButtonItem *leftBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btnLeft];
[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:leftBarButton];
//
// Set navigation right button
btnRight = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[btnRight setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button_signup.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btnRight addTarget:self action:@selector(nextImage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[btnRight setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 29)];
[btnRight setTitle:@"Next" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btnRight setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btnRight.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Futura" size:15.0]];
UIBarButtonItem *rightBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btnRight];
[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:rightBarButton];
//
```

Answer (score 1):

This example should solve your problem: http://rogchap.com/2011/06/21/custom-navigation-bar-background-and-custom-buttons/ .. originally answered here - > [Custom Navigation Bar Buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13662971/custom-navigation-bar-buttons)..